# Google Earth Engine Javascript - Add metadata properties list of string

Tags: google-earth-engine, metadata

I'm looking fo add a List of Strings value to properties of an image collection in google earth similar to Copernicus CORINE Land Cover:
[https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_CORINE_V20_100m#image-properties](https://I%27m%20looking%20fo%20add%20a%20List%20of%20Strings%20value%20to%20properties%20of%20an%20image%20collection%20in%20google%20earth%20similar%20to%20Copernicus%20CORINE%20Land%20Cover:%20https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_CORINE_V20_100m#image-properties)

I tried this code:

```
var assetId = 'your-image-collection-id'

var lis = "one"

// Update the properties of the asset in Earth Engine.
var task =ee.data.setAssetProperties(assetId, {
'prova': lis})
```

It works but It doesn't accept list

then I tried this other code:

```
// ID dell'Image Collection 
var collectionId = 'your-image-collection-id'; 
  // Recupera l'Image Collection 
var collection = ee.ImageCollection(collectionId); 
  // Crea un oggetto JSON che rappresenta le proprietà da inserire 
var newProperties = { 'property_name_1': ['one' , 'two', 'three' ,   ] }; 
  // Aggiorna le proprietà dell'Image Collection 
var updatedCollection = collection.set(newProperties); 
  // Salva le proprietà aggiornate sull'Asset Earth Engine 
var task = ee.data.updateAsset({ assetId: collectionId, properties: newProperties }); 
  // Verifica lo stato della task 
var status = task.status();
```

and this is the error:

*Asset 'projects/earthengine-public/assets/[object Object]' does not exist or doesn't allow this operation*

but the id is correct and the asset is mine.

Any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 1):

While it's hard to tell for sure without accessing the actual asset, it looks like you are mixing server-side and client-side functions, which is why it is registering the id as `[object Object]` rather than its actual value. You may need to do an explicit cast, use `getInfo()` or modify your script to use only server-side functions. More info on this [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server).